# JGIT api exeception

Tags: jgit

I am using JGIT API to clone and push code but facing below mentioned problem with the some git project

Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of fetch command    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:138)    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:175)   at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:121)    at com.huawei.ccm.sync.service.GitSyncservice.cloneGit(GitSyncservice.java:139)     at com.huawei.test.Test.doSync(Test.java:146)   at com.huawei.test.Test.main(Test.java:132) Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Packfile is truncated.   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:229)   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:225)  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:151)    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:113)   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1062)  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:129)    ... 5 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Packfile is truncated.  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1129)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.access$000(PackParser.java:97)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser$InflaterStream.read(PackParser.java:1647)  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)   at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.whole(PackParser.java:974)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.indexOneObject(PackParser.java:908)    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:486)     at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:179)    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:676)     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:284)     ... 11 more

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you were doing with Git when the exception happened?

Comment: I tried to clone one git project. git clone is happening in linux system with same git project but using jgit api it is throws above error

Comment: I know next to nothing about JGit, but I would ask you to try cloning directly from the Git bash.  My guess: You'll have a problem there too, and if you're lucky you might human readable error feedback which will reveal what is going on.

Comment: i don't have any problem  with git bash